# Matlab figure partially covered by header bar

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, figure

I am curious what I need to do to get the header bar to not display over my figure in matlab. It partially covers a button. I can provide more information if requested.

[image]

I call using VB from powerpoint:

```
Call RunFile("WindowAPI(new_control_pan,'Clip',true)", "C:\Users\mhaartman\Documents\PANE_golden2\PANE_golden\code")
```

and I still see the same thing.

Comment: Can you attached a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...Do you just want to remove the menu bar?

Comment: I just want to move the top bar so the buttons are not covered by it. I have tried moving the entire figure down without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs more clarification.. In the meantime, you can hide the menu bar and the toolbar as such:

```
hFig = figure;
plot(sin(1:100))
set(hFig, 'Menu','none', 'Toolbar','none')
```

the resulting figure looks like:

[image: screenshot]

if you are on MS Windows, we can go even further and remove the window borders (make it look like a *splash screen*). This is done by calling native Win32 API from a C MEX-function (I am using the [WindowAPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437) function by Jan Simon on the File Exchange)

```
WindowAPI(hFig,'Clip',true)
```

[image: screenshot_noborders]

Comment: Its the actual bar that says Figure. It is covering buttons on my figure. Not sure how to resize

Comment: @megv: now that I see the screenshot you posted, I don't think it's an issue of hiding toolbars or borders (none of that will solve the issue here)... You are placing the GUI components too high in the figure (`'Position'` property). The solution is either bringing them down a bit, or increasing the height of the figure itself. Just be aware of how the `'Units'` property affect how the position property is interpreted (pixels, normalized units, etc..). Also [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f8-998382.html#f8-1028670) might be helpful.